# variable out of mysql query in bash not filled by local bash variables on echo

Tags: mysql, bash

I would like to query from mysql by bash. In the mysql field is a text "$variable". (it's a html template at all).

In Bash Script you find:

> variable="Text for Template";
>
> test=`/usr/bin/mysql ... -execute"use db; select de from table where id is = '1'`;"

If I do

> echo $test;

I just get $variable and not "Text for Template"

What could I change to get the expected value ? Any ideas ?

For Information:
In the MYSQL DB field is a complete html webpage with diffrent $variables. In past I solved it by insert the complete html webpage as htmlvar="...$variable" into the bash script. This worked good but was uncomfortable because of around 5 web templates. SO I thought if I put the HTML page into Database I could read it to a variable an then I would be filled by the local variables who are in the bash script like in the past. But now I only get the plain text of the DB field and the $variable is not set.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your are probably looking for variable expansion:

```
$ variable="Hello there"
$ test=variable
$ echo ${!test}
>> Hello there
```

Please note, that `test=variable` is without dollar sign (not `test=$variable`). If you have dollar sign and would like to use it as well, you can do double echo:

`` echo `echo $test` ``

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correct but if you want to print your database results you can just do :

$ mysql -u root -p -e "select de from db.table where id is = '1';"

but if you want print the variable value you can do :

$ echo "$variable"

Anyway I believe you can not print "Text for Template" by command "echo $test;" according your code.

Comment: In the DB field is a complete HTML webpage with some $variables. In past I put the complete HTML webpage in the bashscript as htmlvar="<HTML>...</HTML>". This worked also fine. The $variables in the htmlvar were filled. But if I get the value from mysql it do not get filled. I do this because it is more comfortable.

Comment: as far as I know what you will get from DB is plain text but not dynamic. if you would like to grab some special information on it and then assign it to a variable you can pipe your query with some grep or sed command to get exactly what you want and assign it to a variable. then you can use it for later If I understand your situation correctly. I never worked with mySql  queries but work with Cassandra which is almost the same.